# Querying IP addresses (IPv4/IPv6) in Amazon Neptune graph database

Tags: ip-address, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I'm looking for a way to store IP address ranges in Neptune which will enable me later on to run queries based on IP ranges.
Few examples:
1. Find all vertexes with property "address_range" where the address is in the subnet X
2. Find all vertexes with property "address_range" where the address is in not in the subnet Y
3. Find all vertexes with property "address_range" where the address overlaps with subnet Z

Where X,Y,Z are subnets like 62.93.132.186/28.
The same goes for IPv6 ranges.

- I'm using Gremlin (if it matters)

Comment: This question is very specific to gremlin language and data model. Can you please add gremlin tag?

Comment: Are you looking to do an exact match such as property == "62.93.132.186/28" or are you looking to do something more fine grained with the individual IP address based on looking for which CIDR block it falls into?

Comment: I need more than equal for checking ranges. For example, I expect a vertex with range 10.0.0.0/28 to appear in query results for all vertexes in 10.0.0.0/24 @Kelvin Lawrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this with gremlin is to store integers values for your subnets: `fromIp` and `toIp` then you can run a simple query with integer operators like `gte` & `lte` to answer each case:

**contained by subnet X:**

```
g.V().hasLabel('Subnet').has('fromIp', gte(X.fromIp)).has('toIp', lte(X.toIp))
```

**Not contained by subnet Y:**

```
g.V().hasLabel('Subnet').not(
  has('fromIp', gte(Y.fromIP)).
  has('toIp', lte(Y.toIp)))
```

**Overlaps with subnet Z:**

```
g.V().hasLabel('Subnet').where(coalesce(
     has('fromIp', lte(Z.fromIp)).has('toIp', gte(Z.fromIp)),
     has('fromIp', lte(Z.toIp)).has('toIp', gte(Z.toIp),
))
```

example: https://gremlify.com/7g

subnets in db:  10.0.0.0/28, 10.0.0.0/8 , 11.0.0.0/8

test subnet: 10.0.0.0/24(167772161, 167772414):

```
g.inject(1).
  project('contain', 'not-contain', 'overlap').
    by(V().hasLabel('Subnet').
      has('fromIp', gte(167772161)).
      has('toIp', lte(167772414)).values('subnet').fold()).
    by(V().hasLabel('Subnet').
      not(has('fromIp', gte(167772161)).
        has('toIp', lte(167772414))).values('subnet').fold()).
    by(V().hasLabel('Subnet').coalesce(
        has('fromIp', lte(167772161)).
        has('toIp', gte(167772161)),
        has('fromIp', lte(167772414)).
        has('toIp', gte(167772414))
      ).values('subnet').fold())
```