# Converting Ip string to Integer to check if it falls within an CIDR block

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I have a set of vertices that contain a property Ip which is declared as String.

I want to check if this IP is inside a CIDR block or within IP ranges.

Is there a way to convert String up attribute to a number so that I can perform the operation.

Comment: See if the solution here can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61343346/querying-ip-addresses-ipv4-ipv6-in-amazon-neptune-graph-database/61346489#61346489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gremlin today does not have String manipulation steps and operators so you cannot do things like convert Strings to Integers or split and concatenate Strings. It does however have a `math` step.

I see two options:

1. Store the IP as a list of 4 numbers or as four individual properties.
2. Use in-line code (lambdas) to do the work. However many graph DBs do not allow in-line lambda code and in general it is not recommended as a best practice.

If you were able to store the values as a list or as four properties you could then use the `math` step to convert the four bytes into a single decimal number and compare with other numbers.

In the short term, it might be better to store IP addresses as simple 4-byte integer values to make the comparisons easier.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an IP address to integer notation, each section of the IP address (separated by ".") is multiplied by 256x. In this case, x represents the position of the section from right to left, starting with 0. Here is an example using this formula:

`192.168.1.1 = (192 * 256^3) + (168 * 256^2) + (1 * 256^1) + (1 * 256^0)`

Comment: Thanks for adding that. I should have included it in my answer after I suggested using 4 byte integer values.